# Unnamed child node when creating SKLabelNode?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sklabelnode

I have noticed that when using `SKLabelNode` there is a second unnamed node added to the node tree. This node is actually an `SKSpriteNode` which I am assuming is being used to display the text for the label, can anyone confirm this as I can't find any mention of this in the docs. My understanding was that `SKLableNode` was a single self-contained node, I was curious to find out when looking at my display graph that it appears to have brought a friend to the party.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, each label has a single SKSpriteNode child. Presumably the sprite is used to render the texture created from the label's font and text.

You won't find this mentioned in the docs as this is Sprite Kit internal behavior and subject to change.

PS: [SpriteKit-Quicklook](https://github.com/KoboldKit/SpriteKit-QuickLook) helps to find such Sprite Kit anomalies.

Comment: Thank you, thats what I thought, it would however have been nice to know as even though its internal it does add to the node tree and makes for a bit of head scratching when you realise you have more nodes than you thought you should have. Much appreciated, as always ...

Comment: There are lot's of "good to know" things about Sprite Kit Apple isn't telling. ;) For instance how exactly batch-drawing works. That shape nodes aren't batched. What the texture caching behavior is. Etc.

Comment: I will take a look at SpriteKit-Quicklook, I currently have a set of text based tools that monitor the node tree, but your version looks a little more slick. Hopefully the "unknowns" will give Apple room to grow the framework at this years WWDC. It would be nice to have Xcode-Quicklook show more things, its useful but  limited right now, particularly with SpriteKit.